# Load PDF from documents directory - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

Instead of loading a PDF from the resources folder I would like to 
load it from the documents directory. I have been trying to do this 
for days but the CGPDFDocumentRef keeps returning NULL. Here is my 
code:

```
                // Get Documents Directory 
                NSArray *searchPaths = 
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
                NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0]; 
                NSString *tempPath = [documentsDirectoryPath 
stringByAppendingPathComponent:[appDelegate.issueToLoad 
stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"pdf"]]; 
                NSString *path = [tempPath 
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"localhost/" withString:@""]; 
                NSLog(@"PATH: %@", path); 
                //Display PDF 
                CFURLRef pdfURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, 
(CFStringRef)path, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, FALSE); 
                NSLog(@"PDF URL: %@", pdfURL); 
                pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(finalURL); 
                NSLog(@"PDF: %@", pdf);
```

The file path is correct and I have checked the simulator documents 
directory and the file is definitely there. When I run the app the 
last NSLog says (NULL) and a blank white page PDF is displayed. 
Any ideas what is wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: Assuming pdf is a CGPDFDocumentRef, we're using similar code. It works on mine though. Don't see why yours is failing.

Comment: What makes you think “localhost/” is going to be part of the file's pathname, and that you need to cut it out from there? It normally only appears in URLs, but you haven't made a URL yet.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer would be to use the pdfURL in der DocumentCreate function. finalURL comes out of nowhere and it's not apparent what it's even there for.

`pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(pdfURL);`

Answer (score 1):

ok, next try. I hope this time it will be more useful :-/

are you sure the file exists at this path?
I created a testcase similar to yours. And with a file named "file 123.pdf" this seems to work. At least I can read the version of the pdf.

I added this after your code sample to see if the pdf was loaded.

```
NSLog(@"PDF: %@", pdf);
int majorVersion;
int minorVersion;
CGPDFDocumentGetVersion(pdf, &majorVersion, &minorVersion);
NSLog(@"%d %d", majorVersion, minorVersion);
```

and this gives me the following console output:

```
2010-10-08 13:01:40.246 test[3517:207] PATH: /var/mobile/Applications/E9CDCAC1-430D-488E-ABC3-33F40F6A06F4/Documents/file 123.pdf
2010-10-08 13:01:40.252 test[3517:207] URL: file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/E9CDCAC1-430D-488E-ABC3-33F40F6A06F4/Documents/file%20123.pdf
2010-10-08 13:01:40.257 test[3517:207] PDF: <NSCFType: 0x139660>
2010-10-08 13:01:40.260 test[3517:207] 1 4
```

there is clearly a %20 inside, so I think this is not the problem with your implementation.

---

EDIT:
Add this to your code to make sure that the file exists at this path.

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    NSLog(@"File does not exist!");
```

There must be a **valid** pdf-File at your path.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have a PDF file at that path. The “Create” in `CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL` refers to the CGPDFDocument object; it will not create a document file at that URL. You can only create a CGPDFDocument object for a PDF file that already exists.

Also, as I mentioned on your other question, I don't see why you're trying to delete “localhost/” from the path. It's unlikely to exist there in the first place (it's more likely to only appear in the URL), and if it ever does appear there, it *should* appear there, and stripping it out will make the path wrong.